# printing sorted columns based on values in python

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I have a CSV file with 11 columns. I am new to Python and trying to make a code that sorted column 2 alphabetically (string) and then prints the rows of the sorted list.

I only want the rows printed where column 1 == 1.

If column 1 == 0 then i want the script to ignore this row and continue on to the next line without printing it.

```
in_file = open('filename.csv', 'r')
dict = {}

#should print all rows where field [0] == 1

print('List of rows where column one is equal to zero in alphabetical order of column 2')

for line in in_file:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    fields = line.split(',')

    c1 = fields[0]
    c2 = fields[1]
    c3 = fields[2]
    c4 = fields[3]
    c5 = fields[4]
    c6 = fields[5]
    c7 = fields[6]
    c8 = fields[7]
    c9 = fields[8]
    c10 = fields[9]
    c11 = fields[10]

    if c2 not in dict:
        dict[c2] = c1
    if c3 not in dict:
        dict[c3] = c1
    if c4 not in dict:
        dict[c4] = c1
    if c5 not in dict:
        dict[c5] = c1
    if c6 not in dict:
        dict[c6] = c1
    if c7 not in dict:
        dict[c7] = c1
    if c8 not in dict:
        dict[c8] = c1
    if c9 not in dict:
        dict[c9] = c1
    if c10 not in dict:
        dict[c10] = c1
    if c11 not in dict:
        dict[c11] = c1

name = dict.keys()
sorted_names = sorted(name)
for name in sorted_names:
    c1 = dict[name]
    rows = [row for row in in_file if row ['c1']!= 1]

for row in rows:
    print(c3, c2, c4, c5)

in_file.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? You're only telling us what you want the script to do

Comment: Hi, the problem i am having is the code errors out on the line     rows = [row for row in in_file if row ['survived']!= 1] and states TypeError: string indices must be integers. column1 is an integer so a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, the error pops up in the 'rows = [row for row in in_file if row ['c1']!= 1]' line. As far as i know, the error is really simple:

you input indices as strings, but they Always have to be integers, as the error says. for example: your index is ['c1'], but c1 is a variable. using [c1] would probably solve the problem.